# How to implement ng2-ui (NPM package) using Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, systemjs, angular-cli

I wish to use the following NPM package with Angular CLI: [ng2-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ui)

The implementation guide is for SystemJS, and not for Webpack, what is used by ***Angular CLI*, what I have to use in this project.**

**What did I already do?**

- Installed the package by `npm install ng2-ui --save`
- Added the following line to `app.module.ts`

  ```
  import { Ng2UIModule } from 'ng2-ui';
  ```
- Added `Ng2UIModule` to the `imports` array in `@NgModule`.

By this point I didn't use `Ng2UIModule` in any of the components yet and before doing the mentioned operations the application worked just fine.

When I try to run the application by `ng serve`, I get the following error in console:

```
ERROR in [default] C:\tools\test-package.net\node_modules\ng2-ui\dist\index.d.ts:1:31
Cannot find module 'ng2-overlay'.

ERROR in [default] C:\tools\test-package.net\node_modules\ng2-ui\dist\index.d.ts:2:32
Cannot find module 'ng2-map'.

ERROR in [default] C:\tools\test-package.net\node_modules\ng2-ui\dist\index.d.ts:3:60
Cannot find module 'ng2-popup'.

ERROR in [default] C:\tools\test-package.net\node_modules\ng2-ui\dist\index.d.ts:4:39
Cannot find module 'ng2-scrollable'.
```

I guess the application simply lacks the following `systemjs.config.js` settings:

```
map['ng2-ui'] =  'node_modules/ng2-ui/dist';
packages['ng2-ui'] = {main: 'ng2-ui.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}
```

Just I don't know how to make it work in the **Angular CLI** version of Webpack...

(Currently I use Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.17)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi erik

did you find out how to make it works ?

Comment: I eventually used different packages instead. Like [ng2-dnd](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd) for Drag-and-Drop and [ngx-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap) for other UI goodys along with [ng2-select](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select). I hope it helps you @LintonB

Comment: Thanks @Erik Kránicz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ng2-ui has been changed to @ngui/overlay https://github.com/ng2-ui/overlay.

Here is my sample code.

ex.component.html

```html
<div id='div1' class='container row'>
  Div 1


</div>

<div id="overlay" ngui-overlay-of="div1" style='background-color:black'>
  Loading data......
</div>

<div id="overlay2" ngui-overlay-of="div1" style='background-color:blue'>
  Loading data......
</div>

<button (click)="showOverlay($event)" class='btn btn-success'>Show Overlay</button>
<button (click)="hideOverlay()" class='btn btn-danger'>Hide Overlay</button>

<br /><br />
<button (click)="showOverlay2($event)" class='btn btn-success'>Show Overlay</button>
<button (click)="hideOverlay2()" class='btn btn-danger'>Hide Overlay</button>
```

ex.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NguiOverlayManager } from '@ngui/overlay';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ex',
  templateUrl: './ex.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './ex.component.css' ],
  providers:[NguiOverlayManager]
  
})
export class ExComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private overManager:NguiOverlayManager) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  showOverlay(event: Event) { 

    this.overManager.open('overlay',event);
  }

  hideOverlay() { 
    this.overManager.close('overlay');
  }

  showOverlay2(event: Event) {

    this.overManager.open('overlay2', event);
  }

  hideOverlay2() {
    this.overManager.close('overlay2');
  }

}
```

Add `import { NguiOverlayModule } from '@ngui/overlay';` to the module and add NguiOverlayModule to the imports array.